# Styling Kendo Multiselect and Kendo Grid on one Page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to put a Kendo Multiselect above a Kendo Grid.

It's a very simple layout, but I wonder why it doesn't work?

The form is always cluttered, and it has a horizontal scrollbar.

This is the code:

```
<div class="form-group text-right">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.code, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-6" })
            @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.Code)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "" })
            )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<class>()
```

I'm using Bootstrap, but any solution is welcome. It cannot be this hard!

Even without using any Bootstrap code and `div`, I'll get a white page that has horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

The form looks like this:

[image]

If I select anything on the page, items will appear and the scrollbar will be gone!

**UPDATE**

Yes! I hunted it down! It happens when I add a `placeholder`, and when I start typing in the box (Server-side filtering is enabled). Any possible solution?

Comment: Its hard to pin point what is the problem if we can't have same end as yours. I suggest you to inspect the element, and all elements which wrapping your multi-select, and investigate what are CSS properties that applied on it. In Chrome Developer Tools you can see styles tab, and there are checkboxes that you can turn on and off for each CSS property, maybe you can find a clue there.

Comment: Nice suggestion! It's about `k-rtl`. But adding a `direction: ltr` style to the element doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem, but try and simplify your Bootstrap a bit.

Like this:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.code)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.Code))
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<class>() 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Nicholas, even if I don't use any Bootstrap classes, still the form will look like that. And It doesn't have any relation to the grid or anything else. I've tried in many places! It should be something with my site.css I guess.

Comment: Perhaps your Bootstrap and Kendo css are conflicting. Maybe this page helps you: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I've exactly followed those steps. I even removed Bootstrap and site.css from the site! I've tried to use the Kendo example on my page, which was cluttered as well. Any idea about possible problem and debugging steps? I've tried to set width, height, margin and padding for that controller, but the horizontal scrollbar still exists.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is using the debugger in your browser and check if any css styles are affecting the page.

Comment: You can also try posting a screenshot of the debugger, showing the css affecting the controls.

Comment: I'll be grateful if you could take a look at, I did anything but none of them worked. Should I post the `Rules` or the `computed` section?